# What kinds of configuration can prevent a network interface from seeing traffic?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, systemd

I have two ethernet adapters on my Debian system, eth0 on my local network statically assigned to 192.168.2.1, and eth1 with a dynamic IP connected to the internet.

I know this setup works, because it's what I'm using right now. However, currently the server is booted with init=/bin/bash, with me manually mounting /proc, /sysfs, etc., manually enabling RAID, manually mounting disk partitions, manually ifup'ing the interfaces, and manually starting bind and the DHCP server.

However, if I let systemd take over the boot process, this doesn't work. eth1 comes up OK, and I have local access to the internet from the server, and eth0 *says* it's UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST, but I get no traffic through it. If I run iptraf and a ping to another local machine, I see the ARP packets sent but never answered. Pings from machines on the local network get no ARP response, and don't show up as traffic on the server. It's as if the cable was unplugged, except it *is* plugged in - something purely in software is doing this.

So what kinds of (mis)configuration can blackhole all the traffic on an interface like that?

Answer (score 0):

Mucking around with an unrelated part of systemd fixed it. In particular, RAID configuration was causing it to drop into emergency mode, and presumably some part of the startup sequence somehow messed up the ethernet configuration.